# Content Editing in Toolbar Android

Tags: java, c#, android, android-fragments

I have the fragment with the list of chats (pic.1) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SevaL.png).

I can choose one of the chats and go to another fragment like this (pic.2) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnaUc.png). In current fragment my toolbar is different comparing to previous one, as you see. I added title, subtitle and logo programmatically

```
var toolbar = Activity.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
toolbar.Title = "Test";
toolbar.Subtitle = "test";
toolbar.SetLogo(Resource.Mipmap.Icon);
```

If I press the "back" button i will return to the fragment with lists of chats but title, subtitle and logo will be remained on toolbar.

My question is how would it be correctly to return to the source toolbar that is shown at the pic.1? I need correct view of the toolbar regardless of the pressed button.

Doesn't matter what you use in the answer: C# or Java. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just reset them programatically like this

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    var toolbar=     Activity.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    toolbar.Title = "Your original title";
    toolbar.Subtitle = "Your original subtitle";
    toolbar.SetLogo(R.mipmap.original);
}
```

EDIT
Find current fragment like this

```
Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
```

and depending on which fragment the user is viewing change the toolbar accordingly.

Comment: Pressing "back" button supposes that i don't know what fragment i will return to. So, i can't set these properties explicitly

Comment: I edited my answer which will give you a better solution for all cases

Comment: Does your answer suppose that i will be looking for a fragment by its id and then check id in "case" construction?

Comment: Check one of the ids, depending on if the fragment is null and invisible or not null and visible those are your cases.